# Rails how to merge params when defining path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using simple navigation and I am trying to define a path:

```
sub_nav.item t.id,
             t.h1.force_encoding("UTF-8"),
             tag_path( d.slug, t.slug,
               params.merge(:tag_id => t.id, :page => nil)
             )
```

I want to merge the params, but I get the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"kategoris", :action=>"show", :view=>"boks",
  :id=>"vind-gavekort", :tag_id=>26, :page=>nil,
  :kategori=>"gavekort-konkurrencer"}
```

If I change it to:

```rb
sub_nav.item t.id,
             t.h1.force_encoding("UTF-8"),
             tag_path( d.slug, t.slug, :tag_id => t.id, :page => nil )
```

It works, but the params are not merged.

Routes:

```rb
match '/:id' => 'kategoris#show', :as => 'katshow'
match ':kategori/:id' => 'tags#show', :as => 'tag'
```

Comment: what is your route about kategoris controller ?

Comment: just updated the question with the routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **:controller** and **:action** values are not messing around when merging other custom params.
Try this:

`params.except(:controller, :action).merge(:tag_id => t.id, :page => nil)`

Comment: I was going to add a if else statment in the config file.

Comment: In fact, you can do this, to get rid of the pagination as well, without needing to nil it: `params.except(:controller, :action, :page).merge(:tag_id => t.id)`